# Android ADB Open URL in a different browser other than the default

Tags: python, android, browser, automation, adb

How can I start a web browser and search for a website with adb other than the default, for example every time I run my code the browser opens in the default chrome app, but what if I wanted it to search the website on Firefox or a different web browser?

```
import time
from ppadb.client import Client as AdbClient
client = AdbClient(host="127.0.0.1", port=5037)
devices = client.devices()

if len(devices) == 0:
    print ('no device attached')
    quit()

device = devices [0]



device.shell('am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d https://smartbear.com/')
```

Comment: does the answer below help to figure out the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use different `am start` commands based on which browser you want to use, for instance (for Chrome):

```
device.shell('am start -n com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main -d https://smartbear.com/')
```

or (Firefox):

```
device.shell('am start -n org.mozilla.firefox/org.mozilla.gecko.BrowserApp -d https://smartbear.com/')
```

or (Chromium webview):

```
device.shell('am start -n org.chromium.webview_shell/org.chromium.webview_shell.WebViewBrowserActivity -d https://smartbear.com/')
```

etc...

Comment: The last one is very helpful +1